# How to validate whether the BBOX strategy works successfully?

Tags: openlayers-2, geojson

I want to send requests to our feature server that asks only data within
the viewable map extent. So I've used BBOX strategy and HTTP Protocol as
following code.

```
        mVectorLayer = new OpenLayers.Layer.Vector("Overlay", {
            **strategies: [new OpenLayers.Strategy.BBOX()],**
            protocol: new OpenLayers.Protocol.HTTP({
                url: 'http://localhost:56786/jlist.geojson',
                format: new OpenLayers.Format.GeoJSON({
                    'read': myReadFunction,
                    'internalProjection': map.baseLayer.projection,
                    'externalProjection': new OpenLayers.Projection("EPSG:4326")
                })
            }),
            projection: new OpenLayers.Projection("EPSG:900913")
        });
```

I've added a feature outside the viewable map to the geojson file shown at below.

```
{ "type": "FeatureCollection",
  "features": [
      { "type": "Feature",
        "geometry": {"type": "Point", "coordinates": [29.0, 41.060]},
        "properties": {"name": "IST J1", "img": "img/marker.png"}
      },
      { "type": "Feature",
        "geometry": {"type": "Point", "coordinates": [29.0, 41.100]},
        "properties": {"name": "IST J2", "img": "img/marker.png"}
      },
      **{ "type": "Feature",
        "geometry": {"type": "Point", "coordinates": [59.0, 41.100]},
        "properties": {"name": "IST J3", "img": "img/marker.png"}
      }**
  ]
}
```

To validate, I've added an alert to the function myReadFunction which shows
the json string. But the alert shows all features in geojson file. I
suppose our feature server sends all geojson content instead of viewable
features? How can I validate or observe whether the BBOX strategy works successfully?

```
    function myReadFunction(json, type, filter) {
        **alert("json: " + json);**

        type = (type) ? type : "FeatureCollection";
        var results = null;
        var obj = null;
        if (typeof json == "string") {
            obj = OpenLayers.Format.JSON.prototype.read.apply(this, [json, filter]);
        } else {
            obj = json;
        }
        if (!obj) {
            OpenLayers.Console.error("Bad JSON: " + json);
        } else if (typeof (obj.type) != "string") {
            OpenLayers.Console.error("Bad GeoJSON - no type: " + json);
        } else if (this.isValidType(obj, type)) {
            switch (type) {
                case "Geometry":
                    try {
                        results = this.parseGeometry(obj);
                    } catch (err) {
                        OpenLayers.Console.error(err);
                    }
                    break;
                case "Feature":
                    try {
                        results = this.parseFeature(obj);
                        results.type = "Feature";
                    } catch (err) {
                        OpenLayers.Console.error(err);
                    }
                    break;
                case "FeatureCollection":
                    // for type FeatureCollection, we allow input to be any type
                    results = [];
                    switch (obj.type) {
                        case "Feature":
                            try {
                                results.push(this.parseFeature(obj));
                            } catch (err) {
                                results = null;
                                OpenLayers.Console.error(err);
                            }
                            break;
                        case "FeatureCollection":
                            for (var i = 0, len = obj.features.length; i < len; ++i) {
                                try {results.push(this.parseFeature(obj.features[i]));
                                } catch (err) {
                                    results = null;
                                    OpenLayers.Console.error(err);
                                }
                            }
                            break;
                        default:
                            try {
                                var geom = this.parseGeometry(obj);
                                results.push(new OpenLayers.Feature.Vector(geom));
                            } catch (err) {
                                results = null;
                                OpenLayers.Console.error(err);
                            }
                    }
                    break;
            }
        }
        return results;
```

}

Thanks a lot for your helps and explanations,
Yasemin

Answer (score 2):

you are requesting data from a user without specifying the BBOX of features you want the server to return, so I understand the server is always returning a data no matter if their inside/outside the BBOX.

Note new OpenLayers.Strategy.BBOX() strategy is used to update the data (request again) when the map's viewport change.
If you want to request the data form a file only once and not refresh when the map is panned then use the new OpenLayers.Strategy.Fixed() strategy.

To check your features you can create a map listener on the "moveend" event, then get the features from your layer and check which are withint the map viewport BBOX.

Cheers.

Comment: Note, the book OpenLayers Cookbook (http://www.packtpub.com/openlayers-create-gis-web-applications-cookbook/book) has some nice recipes to deal with features and events.